# How to run a buffer through a gulp plugin?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to write a function that lets you use **any gulp plugin** as a simple in-memory buffer-transformer (hiding away all the stream/vinyl stuff). For example, it could be called like this:

```
const gulpMinifyHtml = require('gulp-minify-html');

transformBufferWithGulpPlugin(inputBuffer, gulpMinifyHtml()).then(outputBuffer => {
    // outputBuffer should now be a minified version of inputBuffer
});
```

(NB. I'm looking for a generic way to do this with *any* gulp plugin; gulp-minify-html is just an example.)

---

It seems like it would be easy but I'm tearing my hair out trying to make it work. I think what I need to do is:

1. construct a new `Vinyl` instance with contents set to `inputBuffer`
2. put this vinyl instance into an object stream (?)
3. pipe the object stream through the gulp plugin
4. collect output from the stream
5. when the stream is finished outputting, grab the contents buffer from the vinyl instance, and resolve with it.

Are those steps basically correct? Can anyone show me a working example, or point me to a module that does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. This uses [`stream-array`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-array) to create the stream.

```
var File = require('vinyl');
var streamify = require('stream-array');

function transformBufferWithGulpPlugin(inputBuffer, gulpPlugin) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    streamify([new File({path:'dummy', contents:inputBuffer})])
      .pipe(gulpPlugin)
      .on('error', reject)
      .on('data', function(file) {
        resolve(file.contents);
    });
  });
}

var minify = require('gulp-html-minify');

transformBufferWithGulpPlugin(new Buffer('<p>\n Test \n</p>'), minify())
  .then(function(result) {
     console.log(result.toString());
  }, function(error) { 
     console.error(error);
  });
```

It's not strictly necessary to specify a dummy `path` as I do above (`vinyl` doesn't require it), but some plugins might only work if there is a `path` property.

Comment: Thanks, this works great for one plugin I tested ([gulp-template](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-template)) but not for others ( [gulp-autoprefixer](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer), [gulp-clean-css](https://github.com/scniro/gulp-clean-css) and others). In the non-working examples, the data event fires OK and, but the `file.contents` passed to `resolve` seems to contain the original, untransformed source. Can you think of any reason why this might be? I have verified these plugins work in a regular gulpfile with the same options.

Comment: Tried it for both plugins. Works fine.

Comment: Hm ok I'll try again